# CSS issue with Table that contains images from database

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin, html-table

I'm working on a project where I've made my phpmyadmin database spit out a set of 6 images on my webpage. I've put it into a table and this is where the trouble begins - even though it sounds easy!

I need the images to be in three's, in a horizontal line.

I will have 6 images most of the time so 3 per row with good spacing/padding etc.

I've tried a lot of things and played around with the CSS but couldn't get it to work.

Here are (respectively) the actual page and how it looks, the CSS for it and the actual code/script of the table:

Actual Page:

[image]

CSS for the table:

```
table.Evidence td {
                   padding:0px, 10px, 0px, 0px;
                 }
```

Script for the table:

```
<table class = "Evidence" border="1">
          <tr>
            <?php
                  $result=$manager->getPicturePcn($_SESSION["pcn_id"]);
                  $i=0;
                  if($result->rowCount()==0){
                      echo'<td>Empty</td>';
                  }
                  while($picture=$result->fetch()){

                     $destination='picturepcn/'.$picture['picturefine_name'];
                     $i++;
                     if($i==4){

                       echo '<tr><td><img src="'.$destination.'" alt="'.$picture['picturefine_name'].'"/></td>';
                     }else{

                       echo '<td><img src="'.$destination.'" alt="'.$picture['picturefine_name'].'"/></td></tr>';
                     }

                  }

            $result->closeCursor();?>
        </tr>
</table>
        <br><br>
```

It looks very easy but I couldn't make it work as it has PHP included as well. I've still yet to find a working solution.

I need the 6 images as follows:

IMG1 (spacing)
 IMG2 (spacing) 
 IMG3~~~Spacing-NEXT LINE~~~
 IMG4 (spacing)
 IMG5 (spacing) 
 IMG6

Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm new so please bear with me until I get used to this.

Answer (score 0):

`padding` should be separated with spaces, not commas

```
table.Evidence td {
  padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

As for the lines issue, you may want to try using CSS `float` poperty
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Plenty of examples available out there